# Grouping NSArray of NSDictionary based on a key in NSDictionay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to filter out a NSArray of NSDictionaries. With my below example, I want dict1, dict2 & dict4 grouped in one array, dict3 & dict5 grouped in second array and dict6 in third array.

I am getting this data in NSArray, so essentially the "orig" array below is my input and I know that I need to do grouping based on "Name" key.

Instead of looping through the NSArray I though of using valueForKeyPath to return me array based on the key path but this does not work (crashes with logs -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray').

Any suggestion.

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"Name" : @"T1", @"Age" : @"25"};
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"Name" : @"T1", @"Age" : @"25"};
NSDictionary *dict3 = @{@"Name" : @"T2", @"Age" : @"27"};
NSDictionary *dict4 = @{@"Name" : @"T1", @"Age" : @"25"};
NSDictionary *dict5 = @{@"Name" : @"T2", @"Age" : @"27"};
NSDictionary *dict6 = @{@"Name" : @"T3", @"Age" : @"28"};

NSArray *orig = @[dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5, dict6];

NSMutableArray *final = [NSMutableArray array];

final = [orig valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.Name"];

NSLog(@"Final = %@", final);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell if what you want is three different arrays where each one only contains entries with a specific `Name` value (as your first paragraph suggests) or if you want a single array where the entries are sorted by `Name` (as your second paragraph suggests). Regardless,

To sort `orig` by the value of the `Name` field:

```
NSArray *sortedByName = [orig sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES]]];
```

To get a new array by selecting only entries with a specific value for `Name`:

```
NSArray *t1Only = [orig filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name = %@", @"T1"]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I do not want to sort the existing array. I want to have different arrays containing only specific data. In your second approach I need to know the value to feed in the predicate which I do not know. I simply want to get different arrays with unique key values.

Answer (score 3):

If the desired output is an array of arrays, you can get there by building a dictionary keyed by the name attribute in the orig dictionaries:

```
- (NSArray *)collateByName:(NSArray *)original {

    NSMutableDictionary *collate  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSDictionary *d in original) {
        NSString *newKey = d[@"Name"];
        NSMutableArray *newValue = collate[newKey];
        if (!newValue) {
            newValue = [NSMutableArray array];
            collate[newKey] = newValue;
        }
        [newValue addObject:d];
    }
    return [collate allValues];
}
```

It's a little verbose, but clear, I think.  If you want to decide the attribute to distinguish with programmatically, pass in another param called attribute and replace the literal @"Name" with it.

Comment: Thankyou! Actually I was looking for something without FOR loop. I am sure this should work though! Upvoting!

Comment: Glad it's a little helpful.  The requirement is intrinsically iterative.  Another approach may hide the loop, but a loop will be in the solution somewhere, maybe (and I agree preferably) hidden in an SDK method.

Comment: saved my day bro !